# How to connect the Bose QuietComfort 35 I's microphone to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microphone, bose

How to connect the Bose QuietComfort 35 I's microphone to Windows 7?

My Bose QuietComfort 35 I's headphone is connected to Windows 7 but not the microphone:

[image]

[image]

The microphone is supposed to work:

[image]

[image]

Clicking on connect doesn't do anything:

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNtQOW